# Making an Reducer immutable in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have just started of with ImmutableJS and I want to make an reducer Immutable. I've read that I need to convert my reducer back in order for this to work. Anyone that could come up with an answer of how to make this work? Per se I get the error message: "INCREASE_NUMBER.toObject() is not a function" Here's the code(below) :

```
import { INCREMENT } from '../actionTypes/default'
import { Map, toObject } from 'immutable'

const INCREASE_NUMBER = (state = Map({number: 0}), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
    return state.merge({number: state.number + 1})
    default:
    return state
  }
};
INCREASE_NUMBER.toObject()

module.exports = INCREASE_NUMBER
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make a reducer immutable"? Normally it's the *state* that's immutable.

Comment: Kinda seems like you don't know what immutability is

Comment: Thats kinda why I asked this question, to get a understanding of ImmutableJS ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reducer is a function - a pure function that does not hold on to any state. E.g. immutability does not make sense in terms of a reducer.

Immutability refers to data structures, not functions. In React and Redux, it is a good practice to make your state immutable, e.g. design your reducer functions in a way that they always return immutable data structures. But this does not apply to the reducer itself - that's just a function.

```
import { INCREMENT } from '../actionTypes/default'
import { Map } from 'immutable'

export default (state = Map({number: 0}), action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            // return new Immutable data structure here
            return state.update('number', num => num + 1);
        default:
             return state;
    }
};
```

The above example is very similar to your original code, except we don't need `toObject` from immutableJS, and I have optimized the state update.

What is immutable here? All the state:

- the default state, given as a default value to the `state` parameter, is a new immutable `Map`;
- the modified state after an INCREMENT action (`Map.prototype.update()` returns a new immutable instance).

This reducer function always returns immutable data, which is great. This is how immutability is implemented in case of reducers: their return values should be immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer iaretiga, unfortunately state.update doesn't update the number :/ any suggestions?

Comment: Even André Stensberg: it doesn't update the number in the original state, as it's an immutable Map (e.g. it cannot be changed, or mutated). It returns a new immutable Map, which contains a an updated number. Check this fiddle (ES5, but otherwise the same code): [Immutable reducer demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iaretiga/4bz75tee/)

Comment: Could you refactor the code? It looks a bit unreadable for me to read. Why do you set state || map?

Comment: Tried to say that state.update('number', function(num) { return num + 1 }); didn't work for me. Is there any way to do this, perhaps with merge() ?

Comment: It works now @iaretiga , I used value: state.number in my mapDispatchToProps. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question, it seems like you don't really understand immutability all that well and I therefore question the legitimacy of your need to use ImmutableJS in the first place. You don't have to use ImmutableJS to write non-mutating state transformations.

I don't need outlet covers to prevent myself from poking metal objects into the electrical outlet. I'd rather not be electrocuted, so I don't go poking things into the outlet all willy nilly. It's not anymore complicated than that.

You're better off developing an intimate understanding of the tools you're working with. You should know when JavaScript operators/functions/methods are mutating data and when they're not. If you think ImmutableJS can protect you from your own ignorance, you'll be making a big mistake. You'll run into problems at some point and have no idea how to diagnose them because you didn't take the time to understand what you're doing.

Your reducer can be written with no-nonsense vanilla JavaScript

```
import { INCREMENT } from '../actionTypes/default'

const initialState = {number: 0}

const increaseNumberReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return {number: state.number + 1}
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default increaseNumberReducer
```

No mutations here. Mutation is fundamentally impossible the way this code is written. We are *reading* a value from `state` but there is no code here that could *write* to the existing `state` object. `state` is not an *immutable* object, but you're not a dumb developer either. If you wrote some code to mutate the `state` object, that's your own fault. You only have yourself to blame if you go poking around in the electrical outlet.

I could have just as easily wrote

```
// non-mutating state transformation
case INCREMENT:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {number: state.number + 1})
```

... and you should know how that differs from

```
// mutating state transformation
case INCREMENT:
  return Object.assign(state, {number: state.number + 1})
```

---

Likewise, you should know the difference between

```
// non-mutating array transformation
[1,2,3].concat([4])
```

... and this

```
// mutating array transformation
[1,2,3].push(4)
```

---

And how about this

```
// mutating sort
[4,2,1,3].sort()
```

... and this

```
// non-mutating sort
[4,2,1,3].slice(0).sort()
```

---

Sure, if you had a big app, someone might argue it'd make sense to add a small immutability safety precaution around your data. This might prevent ignorant developers from *accidentally* mutating `state` when they're not supposed to. To me, this isn't a valid solution tho. If this is a redux app, your developers should have intimate knowledge of redux philosophy, and that means that reducers are pure functions and `state` is never to be mutated... There is no substitute for knowledge and wisdom.

Come to know JavaScript intimately. Learn the tools you're working with. Identify the pros and cons of various methods. Understand the "costs" of various techniques. Know when and where you can make compromises. If you still decide to use ImmutableJS at the end of all that, you'll know *why* you chose it and you'll know the gains/losses that come with it.

Comment: I'm trying to get the grasp of ImmutableJS in this case and not regular JS. The reason is really simple, to work with this in a larger scale. Thanks for the feedback, though!

Comment: I knew I had to vote this up as soon as I saw the phrase "all willy nilly". (But the rest of your answer makes sense too...)

Comment: Thanks for this...I had jumped into both Redux and Immutable.js at the same time, and was getting frustrated with all the getters and setters and difficultly viewing state at run-time....this is what I need -- to take one step back and think about doing immutability without a library ( and having viewable objects at runtime )

Answer (score 0):

In you case here, `INCREASE_NUMBER` is just a function, so calling `toObject` on it makes no sense.

From what I understand, `toObject` is a function that can be called on immutable objects to convert them to JS objects. However, there also is `merge` function that's used to extend a `Map`, and the state value seems to be a `Map`, not a JS object, so why do you want to use `toObject` anywhere in here?

Just drop that `toObject` line.

If the intent was to make the reducer return a JS object instead of a `Map`, you'd have to put it inside the function in the `return` statement. However, taking a `Map` and returning an object seems like a wrong approach to reducers. The state that goes in and out should be the same shape.

Comment: could you edit your comment with an code example for me to fully understand? Tried .toJS() as well but got the same error.

Comment: Don't call anything on the function. Call on return values. E.g. `return state.toObject()` and `return state.merge(...).toObject()`

Comment: Did that, now state.merge is not a function. Any suggestions?

Comment: removed merge and replaced with Map, and now it seems to work, but why isn't merge valid?

Comment: I strongly suggest avoiding toJS and toObject in your reducer code. They're the number one source of performance issues. 

You certainly don't have to use Immutable.js to treat your data as immutable, if you want to always operate on plain objects. Immutable.js is useful when you have collections like Map and List that you want to operate on immutably. Then you should just always treat them as Immutable.js collections and avoid converting to plain JS objects.

Comment: Also, how are you using the reducer? It sounds like you may be providing plain JS objects as state instead of Immutable.js Maps if you see "merge is not a function" errors

Comment: Its just an counter that returns state + 1. My impression of Immutable was that you need to convert back to plain JS every time you want to return something or export them. Targeting the .toJS() issue, what is the intended use case for that?

Comment: Could I use Record() for this instead perhaps?

Comment: You definitely do not want to convert back to plain JS to use them, that conversion will be both expensive and error-prone. When using Immutable.js, stay with those structures as much as possible. Use the .get() method to read values in your component code.

Comment: The use cases for .toJS() are limited. If you have to provide a deep structure to some lib that doesn't operate on general principles like Iterables (many data-vis libs) or to serialize to localStorage or the network.

Comment: You can use Record for the use case here, but using Map is also perfectly fine. That's up to your preference.